# Pronunciation of u

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

All books and dictionaries (notably Wiktionary) that transcribe french pronunciation by means of IPA transcribe the pronunciation of “u” as /y/. But the transcription uses /.../ as opposed to [...]. When I use [y] in my speech, my teacher corrects me and says [ʏ]. Could it be the case that all these textbooks and dictionaries use /y/ instead /ʏ/ in the open transcriptions, and that this is inaccurate?

TL;DR: Should “u” be pronounced [y] ([close front rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel)) or [ʏ] ([near-close near-front rounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_rounded_vowel))?

Resolution: I mistook [y̠] ([close front compressed vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_rounded_vowel#Close_front_compressed_vowel)) for [ʏ] due to my lacking knowledge of the diacritic. A cognitive bias, if you will.

Comment: Do you know where your teacher did learned/practiced French?

Comment: North-eastern France. But upon further examination, it occurs to me that [Y] might be slightly inaccurate, and that [y̠] would be better. My untrained ears perceived the [y̠] as [Y]. The word in question was « eu » (of avoir), a word to which I assume that laxness not apply. If this be the case, I was simply wrong about what I heard, lacked the knowledge of the diactiric ⟨  ͍ ⟩ and made an erroneous post online. Thank you for linking me the aticles; I thought I already knew the sound ([y]) well, but I failed to consider centralisation, so they resolved my nonexistent issue.

Comment: It could easily be an issue for others, so thanks for the question anyway! But might I say that if you can accurately distinguish those three sounds as a learner of French, kudos to your accurate ear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always use the lower case /y/ but it looks like phonologists do not agree about how to represent this vowel.

See the articles discussing [ʏ] on [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyelle_pr%C3%A9-ferm%C3%A9e_ant%C3%A9rieure_arrondie) versus [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-close_near-front_rounded_vowel).

The [Canadian French pronunciation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_phonology) might also play a role here:

> The lax allophone of a high vowel may also appear in open syllables by assimilation to a lax vowel in a following syllable: musique 'music' can be either [myzɪk] or [mʏzɪk].

In France, using [ʏ] would betray an English accent and using [u] a Spanish/Italian/Portuguese one one. Germans do pronounce the [y] correctly because it is part of their phonetics (*ü* / *ue* / *y* ). On the other hand, the French vowel "u" is foreign to English ears so what is used is the closest familiar vowel which happen to be [ʏ].

Answer (score 2):

As I learned it in my linguistics undergrad, the usage is systematic. Your best bet to cover most cases is to pronounce it [y] in open syllables and [ʏ] in closed syllables.

In European French, this sound is always [y] — at least nominally.

However, in every dialect of French, there is a tense/lax realization of certain vowels, where the tense variant appears in an open syllable and the lax version in a closed syllable.

This rule can't be applied universally since some high vowels lack lax variants in European French: /i/, /u/, and /y/. But in Québec, these vowels do have lax variants: [ɪ], [ʊ], and [ʏ] respectively.

The rule is the same for these pairs as for others:

> *ici* [i] **vs.** *icitte* [ɪ] *
>   
> *roue* [u] **vs.** *route* [ʊ]
>   
> *du* [y] **vs.** *chute* [ʏ]

As [the Wikipedia article jlliagre shared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quebec_French_phonology) says, a lax vowel in a closed syllable can also [harmonize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_harmony) a nearby tense vowel, e.g. [ɪ] in *musique* harmonizing [y] to [ʏ]. (This effect is less predictable.)

---

<sub>* An undergrad paper I wrote hypothesizes that innovative forms like *icitte* and *frette*, whose origins are hard to identify, could have co-evolved with these lax vowels, as if to produce more occasions to use them and thereby further differentiate Québécois French for sociolinguistic reasons. Take that for what you will. :)</sub>

Comment: Does it mean anything that I use different variants for different words, like I feel _musique_ is not lax whereas _sud_ is very much so; do you think some of my familiarity with the English language affects how I pronounce words that share more of the same morphology? Thanks!

Comment: @Améraldor If I'm trying to analyze my own speech, I pick a few words sharing a structure, alert a linguistically savvy family member that I'm trying to find out what I say, and then try to put it out of mind while waiting for them to catch un-self-conscious occurrences from me. :) Only then do I draw conclusions about why I do one thing or the other. But in any case, if you mean the /y/ in both of those, it seems to me that the harmony rule isn't the most common. I wonder, are both vowels lax in your *icitte*, if you say that? I feel like that's one where it's more consistent...

Comment: @Améraldor One thing I learned while writing that paper was that languages as a whole influence each other's phonology on a very small scale compared to the lexicon, for example. On the other hand, I find it easy for my speech to alter to match that of people I like, and I hear this anecdotally confirmed by others. So your knowledge of English might have less effect on your French than the interesting French accent of a good Anglophone friend!

Comment: Definitely a gradation of lax from *muse* to *musique* to *sud* for me. So indeed, *musique* wouldn't be an extreme example of lax, though it would still be one...

Comment: I'd go look at Picard, or some other oil variety, for the source of *frette*. At least in my area (transitional between Picard and Walloon) /frɛt/ and /fre:t/ are the equivalents of froide. (likewise, /drɛt/ for droite)

Comment: @Eauquidort The meaning I know, but the final /t/ doesn't seem to be the feminine marker: it also appears in e.g. [*ton p'tit trois-et-demi, ben trop cher, frette en hiver*](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_mes_aieux_11881/paroles_degenerations_403370.html). One theory was that such final /t/s were generalized from liaison. There were also names (Brunet, Chabot, Pouliot...) where the final *t* was perhaps just never dropped — similarly for "*nuitte*" and "*juillette*". But if I remember right, there were contexts like *icitte* where it seemed like it had to be an innovation.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful comments! For _icitte_, no, it's like ee from _wee_ and pretty much _sit_ like in English from my perspective... It's possible I see 3 states and not 2 or that I can do both lax/not lax with a word like _musique_, and I would associate lax with a more basiclectal type of speech...

Comment: Incidentally, I was listening to CBC in French recently and hearing the interviewees say *pipeline* /piˈplɪn/ while the host clearly said /piˈplin/.